# ckeditor are not showing?

Tags: php, jquery

code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/sample/js/sample.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".chk").click(function(){
                id = this.id;  
                $.ajax({
                  type:"POST",
                  data:{"student_id":id},
                  url:"send-mail.php",
                  success:function(data){
                    $("#subject_message").html(data);
                  }
                });
              });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <?php          
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM students";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
        echo "<tr>
                  <td>
                  <input type='checkbox' class='chk' id='".$row['student_id']."' name='student_id[]' value='".$row['student_id']."'>
                  </td>
              </tr>";
        } 
    ?>
    <div id="subject_message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

send-mail.php

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['student_id'];
?>
<?php
    echo "<input type='textbox' name='subject' id='subject_".$id."' placeholder='Enter Subject' />
          <textarea class='ckeditor' rows='9' cols='60' name='message' id='message_".$id."'></textarea>
          <input type='submit' name='send' id='send' value='send mail' />";
?>
```

In this code I am loading external page using jquery/ajax  i.e send-mail.php where I am defining ckeditor class i.e. (class='ckeditor') but when I click on checkbox ckeditor are not showing only simple subject textbox and textarea are showing. So, how can I fix this issue ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change send-mail.php as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<?php
    $id = $_POST['student_id'];
?>
<?php
    echo "<input type='textbox' name='subject' id='subject_".$id."' placeholder='Enter Subject' />
          <textarea class='ckeditor' rows='9' cols='60' name='message' id='message_".$id."'></textarea>
          <input type='submit' name='send' id='send' value='send mail' />";
?>
```

Comment: is `ckeditor/ckeditor.js` correct direction to `ckeditor.js` file?

Comment: there is one more problem @amir the problem is when I check one checkbox it show ckeditor but when I check on another checkbox it show simple text area .